# Visual Studio - ssis project for database on server

Tags: ssis, visual-studio-2017

I am using Visual Studio 2017.  I am trying to create an SSIS project that works on a database I have on a server. I have the project and solution. How do I say, use this DB as source so I can create a NEW ssis package ?

Thanks
Heather F

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new connection manager at either the package or project level.  More details on these and their scopes are as follows.

- **Package Level**-  When the package is open in the designer, the Connection Managers window will be docked below the Control Flow.  Right-click within this area go to `New Connection...`, highlight the OLEDB type and press `Add...`  On the dialog that comes up, press the `New...` button and enter the server name that will be connected to, the authentication type (and username/password for SQL Server authentication) and the database to connect to.  This database will be the initial catalog that any SQL statements will be sent to, unless they use a three part object name with the database (i.e. Database.Schema.Table).  Verify the connection is successful through the Test Connection button.  This connection manager is only available to the package that it is created in.
- **Project Level-** In the Solution Explorer (if you don't see this, go to `View` on the top menu, then `Solution Explorer`), right-click the `Connection Managers` folder and select `New Connection Manager`.  You can also do this from the `Project` drop-down on the top menu and choosing the same option.  From here, you will follow the same steps as with the package level connection manager, beginning with selecting the OLEDB provider type.  This connection manager will be available to all packages within the project it was created in.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to write this out. I usually know what to do, but find it difficult as to where I can do it .

Answer (score 0):

Go in the **Connection Managers** pane and create a new connection, specific to your database type. 
Then you can convert the connection to be a **Project Connection**(by right clicking on it).

Comment: Thanks, but this is where I struggle. How do I go in "Connection Managers" Pane? The menus are non-intuitive.